# Maven in Intellij IDEA cannot resolve symbol env.HOSTNAME

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, environment-variables, hostname, ubuntu-11.10

I searched all over for a resolution to this problem, but could not find anything specific to my setup.  Finally, one of our sys admins figured it out.

I am running Intellij IDEA on Ubuntu 11.10.  My Maven pom.xml file was unable to resolve a symbol, a system property environmental variable env.HOSTNAME.

Comment: I dared to move you edit to a separate answer. If you ever come back here, instead of editing this question post an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

*Copy from user1141627 answers' edit*:

---

It turns out that we had to manually set this variable from the terminal so Java would recognize it.  The command was:

```
set env HOSTNAME yourhostname
```

After restarting Intellij, env.HOSTNAME resolved just fine.  To get yourhostname, you can use the command:

```
hostname
```

or

```
echo $HOSTNAME
```

I realize this is not a question, it is an answer.  Hopefully someone finds it useful if they come across a similar problem.

Comment: So this did not work in the end.  Here is the final solution.  Add the line export HOSTNAME=yourhostname to your ~/.bashrc file.  After you restart your terminal, env.HOSTNAME should resolve just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but my answer might help somebody.

Add `export HOSTNAME=myhost` to your **~/.profile** file, and reboot your computer.